Cygwin.S was not found
When I debug C++ files in VScode, every time I encounter the creation of dynamic array, it will tell me that Cygwin.S file is not found. I think the reason is that the array may be out of bounds, but even if I create an array of length 3, it will still give me this error
I used g++ 4.1 and g++8.1 respectively and this problem occurred. I used mingw's g++ compiler. This happens no matter how small the range of the dynamic array I set

Sounds like an installation problem. Have you mixed cygwin and mingw? (Also, g++ 4.1 is over seventeen years old. There is very little reason to be using it, and it's a bit surprising that you even have it.)

I guessing that something is crashing, gdb is trying to load the source file to show you information, Cygwin.S not being found isn't your error, its just the debugger saying it cant show you the source code, you should look at the source stack for more information

With "dynamic array", do you mean something like int N = 3; int arr[N];  ? Because that is not allowed in C++. The proper "dynamic array" in C++ is std::vector<T> from #include <vector>.

Like @molbdnilo said GCC 4.1 is really old, but GCC 8.1 is also more than 11 years old. Latest version is 14.2. You can get a standalone Windows build from https://winlibs.com/ . Also when gdb tells you Cygwin.S is not found that's probably just a warning, as it's just looking for source code to show in the debugger. The Cygwin.S is used in MinGW-w64/GCC to implement stack checking routines, so if the debugger stops there you know it's related to stack issues. Try to use heap (malloc()/free()) instead of stack memory for dynamic stuff and avoid recursive functions.
